# Run-time eror '3004' write to file failed when downloading file

Tags: vba, ms-word

im trying to download a file using vba but get "Run-time error '404': Write to file failed." when saving to file

```
Dim myURL As String
myURL = "http://example.com/file.exe"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
WinHttpReq.Send

myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oStream.Open
oStream.Type = 1
oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
oStream.SaveToFile "C:\file.exe", 1
oStream.Close
End If
```

Comment: its a 3004 error the file it downloads is an exe

Comment: Which line produces the error?  is it `.SaveToFile`?

Comment: yes. its the .SaveToFile

Comment: yeah I found the issue, one line was buggy.  Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48968766/8112776) below, I've used it with countless filetypes and source sites without a problem (no references are required.)

Answer (score 1):

I've also tried downloading a `.exe` file and got it working. Try the way I've demonstrated below (it's a working one):

```
Sub demo()
    Dim HTTP As New XMLHTTP60
    myURL$ = "https://10gbps-io.dl.sourceforge.net/project/exe/Updates/eXe-install-1.04.1.3590.exe"

    With HTTP
        .Open "GET", myURL, False
        .send
    End With

    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .Type = 1
        .write HTTP.responseBody
        .SaveToFile "D:\Test\Files\" & "3590.exe"  
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft XML, V6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got something weird going on with the line:

```
myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
```

(You're setting the URL to the HTTP response?)

---

## Download any file from a URL:

Instead, just use this sub as a standalone file-downloading procedure:
<sup>*(No references requried.)*</sup>

```
Sub downloadFile(url As String, fileOutPath As String)

    Dim WinHttpReq As Object, oStream As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", url, False
    WinHttpReq.Send

    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile fileOutPath, 1 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
        oStream.Close
    End If

End Sub
```

---

### Example Usage:

> ```
> downloadfile "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip", "c:\tmp_testFile.zip"
> ```

---

### More Information:

- Microsoft.com : **[Stream Object Properties, Methods, and Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/stream-object-properties-methods-and-events)**
- MSDN : **[responseBody Property (IXMLHTTPRequest)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756095(v=vs.85).aspx)**
- MSDN : **[About Native XMLHTTP (IE 5+)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505(v=vs.85).aspx)**
- Chip Pearson's **[Alternate Download Method](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/downloadfile.aspx)** (using Windows API)

Comment: this still gives me "Run-time eror '3004' write to file failed." for some reason

Comment: Then there's a different problem.  Maybe the file is locked by another process.  ***Reboot* and try again**.

Comment: ...and besides rebooting, to confirm: you're using it like `downloadFile "http://example.com/file.exe", "C:\file.exe"`, correct?  And you have write access to the destination folder (ie., you are able to save a Notepad file to `c:\test.txt`?

Comment: It is a common message when the file is locked. Particularly if the file is actually open!

Answer (score 0):

I was also seeing the runtime error that OP had. My problem, it turns out, was that I already had a file at the target destination with the target file name.

By changing

```
oStream.SaveToFile "C:\file.exe", 1 '1= no overwrite
```

to

```
oStream.SaveToFile "C:\file.exe", 2 '2 = overwrite
```

the issue was solved. Another solution is to pick a different file destination.